# Query to get sum of a column based on the date of it's created datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with two columns, `caloriesConsumed` and `createdAt` with datatypes `Int` and `DateTime` respectively. I want to get the sum of the numbers entered on the same date.

```
SELECT SUM(caloriesConsumed), createdAt
FROM record
GROUP BY createdAt;
```

As `createdAt` is of datatype`DateTime`, the columns are not grouped and returns all the records. How can I group by the date and ignore the time in the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `cast(createdAt as date)` to convert the datetime to date

```
select sum(caloriesConsumed), cast(createdAt as date)
    from record
    group by cast(createdAt as date)
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! Can you please tell what would be LINQ query for the same? I need to write a LINQ query in C# for the above